# Change dictionary values with for-loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a dictionary that I want to modify. Not the strings, but only the numbers. The function below should convert all the numbers in the dictionary to two decimal floats:

```
def roundup(resultdict):
    print("resultdict is: " +str(resultdict))
    for item in resultdict.items():
        print("item is: " + str(item))
        if isinstance(item[1], str):
            print("The item {} is a string {}".format(item[0], item[1]))
        else:
            item = list(item) # else Python gives an error it cannot modify a tuple
            item[1] = float("{:.2f}".format(item[1]))
            print("The item {} is now a float {}".format(item[0], item[1]))
    return resultdict

newdict = roundup(resultdict)
print("newdict is: " + str(newdict))
```

This seems to work (although 4 is changed into 4.0, and not into 4.00), but returns the original input? See newdict in the output below.

```
resultdict is: {'standplaats': 'Zagreb', 'totaal': 4215.04, 'totaal_v': 2087.43, 'totaaleenmalig': 16834.78, 'zone': 4, 'categorie': 'A', 'KKC': 0.961, 'ns': 2127.61, 'bs': 2677.58, 'KKC_s': -40.66, 'spvm': 751.82, 'kkc_spvm': -14.66, 'spvp': 526.28, 'kkc_spvp': -13.34, 'spvk': 0.0, 'kkc_spvk': -0.0, 'vh': 502, 'prm': 195, 'kkc_prm': -1.9, 'prp': 68.25, 'kkc_prp': -0.67, 'ovp': 463, 'tv': 314, 'ih': -497.86, 'ibkh': -163.83, 'hk': 3470.14, 'av': 13364.64}
item is: ('standplaats', 'Zagreb')
The item standplaats is a string Zagreb
item is: ('totaal', 4215.04)
The item totaal is now a float 4215.04
item is: ('totaal_v', 2087.43)
The item totaal_v is now a float 2087.43
item is: ('totaaleenmalig', 16834.78)
The item totaaleenmalig is now a float 16834.78
item is: ('zone', 4)
The item zone is now a float 4.0
item is: ('categorie', 'A')
The item categorie is a string A
item is: ('KKC', 0.961)
The item KKC is now a float 0.96
item is: ('ns', 2127.61)
The item ns is now a float 2127.61
item is: ('bs', 2677.58)
The item bs is now a float 2677.58
item is: ('KKC_s', -40.66)
The item KKC_s is now a float -40.66
item is: ('spvm', 751.82)
The item spvm is now a float 751.82
item is: ('kkc_spvm', -14.66)
The item kkc_spvm is now a float -14.66
item is: ('spvp', 526.28)
The item spvp is now a float 526.28
item is: ('kkc_spvp', -13.34)
The item kkc_spvp is now a float -13.34
item is: ('spvk', 0.0)
The item spvk is now a float 0.0
item is: ('kkc_spvk', -0.0)
The item kkc_spvk is now a float -0.0
item is: ('vh', 502)
The item vh is now a float 502.0
item is: ('prm', 195)
The item prm is now a float 195.0
item is: ('kkc_prm', -1.9)
The item kkc_prm is now a float -1.9
item is: ('prp', 68.25)
The item prp is now a float 68.25
item is: ('kkc_prp', -0.67)
The item kkc_prp is now a float -0.67
item is: ('ovp', 463)
The item ovp is now a float 463.0
item is: ('tv', 314)
The item tv is now a float 314.0
item is: ('ih', -497.86)
The item ih is now a float -497.86
item is: ('ibkh', -163.83)
The item ibkh is now a float -163.83
item is: ('hk', 3470.14)
The item hk is now a float 3470.14
item is: ('av', 13364.64)
The item av is now a float 13364.64
newdict is: {'standplaats': 'Zagreb', 'totaal': 4215.04, 'totaal_v': 2087.43, 'totaaleenmalig': 16834.78, 'zone': 4, 'categorie': 'A', 'KKC': 0.961, 'ns': 2127.61, 'bs': 2677.58, 'KKC_s': -40.66, 'spvm': 751.82, 'kkc_spvm': -14.66, 'spvp': 526.28, 'kkc_spvp': -13.34, 'spvk': 0.0, 'kkc_spvk': -0.0, 'vh': 502, 'prm': 195, 'kkc_prm': -1.9, 'prp': 68.25, 'kkc_prp': -0.67, 'ovp': 463, 'tv': 314, 'ih': -497.86, 'ibkh': -163.83, 'hk': 3470.14, 'av': 13364.64}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Floats do not have decimal places.  The floating point value "4" is stored as "4".   The only time you see decimal places is when you PRINT the value.  Make sure you always do `:.2f`.

Comment: `for item in resultdict.items()` This creates a _separate_ variable named `item`.  Assigning to `item[1]` does NOT update the dictionary; it has no connection back to the original dictionary.

Comment: `some_dict.items()` returns an iterator that does not modify original content of `some_dict`, so your modification does not do anything. Moreover, when you assign `item = list(item)`, you stop referring to `item` object yielded by loop iterator. You need to modify `resultdict[key]` instead. And when you do `float(f'{something:.2f}')`, you only round to 2nd decimal place, you do not enforce two digits in later prints of this float (which would be a nonsense).

Comment: what about round(item[1], 2) and then format when printing?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions. The solution was to iterate over key, value pairs and modify the dictionary key with a value, not the iterator. The rounding is now fixed as well.

```
def roundup(resultdict):
    print("resultdict is: " +str(resultdict))
    for key, value in resultdict.items():
        print("item is: " + str(key) + str(value))
        if isinstance(value, str):
            print("The item {} is a string {}".format(key, value))
        else:
            resultdict[key] = "{:.2f}".format(round(value, 2))
            print("The item {} is now a float {}".format(key, value))
    return resultdict

newdict = roundup(resultdict)
print("newdict is: " + str(newdict))
```

Comment: This converts all of your floats to strings.  Is that what you wanted?  If so, you should edit your original question to state that.